# Test who is file's owner using Java

Tags: java

How to test if file belongs to user or operating system using Java?
I'm particularly interested in finding out what are the temporary files generated by the operating system to perform operations such as deletion or modification.

tks.

Comment: I used file.isHidden(), but it includes user and operating system's files and I don't want this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 7, you can use Files.getOwner()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getOwner%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29

Comment: I can't use Java 7 now, but your answer show me one possible resolution. Tks